# Django Storage app, different "upload_to" depending on user's choice

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to implement functionality where user can upload file and choose (in the form) if this file is going to be global (available for everybody) or private (available only for him).
The form would look like this

[image: r]

Firstly I have doubled model, view, form etc. where only difference was:

```py
file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

and

```py
file = models.FileField(upload_to='global files/')
```

is what destroys DRY rule. Obviously it's not what I want to achieve.

So then I tried to make a boolean in the model and changed the `upload_to` parameter depending on the user's choice:

```py
class FileModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    STATUS = (
      (1, ('Global file')),
      (2, ('My file')),
      )
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 30, choices=STATUS, default=2)
    if status == 'My file':
        file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)

    elif status == 'Global file':
        file = models.FileField(upload_to='global files')
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Does anyone has any idea how to implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one of this is enough

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

You don't want to break *DRY* or add a useless `db` column, Let's dive into the form

```
# forms.py 

class MyForm(...):
    ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
       # here you have access to form.data and form.instance (the instance of your model)
       # I'll make it pseudo and you translate to python
       # get what the user chose from form.data in a variable (print it first to see it)
       # edit the form.instance.file depending on it. (instance of your model
       # think of it as my_instance = form.instance)
```